Ticks in radar chartjs 4.4.2
I don't seem to be able to change and set min and max ticks in radar chartjs version 4.4.2... whatever I do, the max ticks is set to the dataset highest value, but I want it to be set to max 100 (no data can be higher than 100 in my dataset)... how can I do this?
This is what I tried with the version 4.4.2 but I guess this is only working with older versions?
options: { scale: { ticks: { min: 0, max: 100 } } }

"What ever I do", care to show us what you have tried code wise in text form so someone can actually figure out what the problem is for you.

As per the documentation, setting the min and max options of the r-scale works fine, see fiddle. Please share a minimal reproducible example that exhibits the issue you describe, so we can identify why the standard options don't work in your case.

I used "ticks" with version 4.4.2 but I guess it only works with older versions? I used scales and "r" now as you suggested in the jsfiddle and it worked just fine!

@EdwinD yes, min and max were inside ticks options in older versions of chart.js, prior to version 3.
